# Why can't I connect MongoDB to nodejs from localhost?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am new to MongoDB and nodejs i created a simple database and tried to connected to my nodejs but I get this error:

```
MongoServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
    at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Users\Solutions\Desktop\MongoDB\node_modules\mongodb\lib\sdam\topology.js:312:38)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:568:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:510:7) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Unknown',
```

MongoDB is running in my PC I can type MongoDB commands I checked in task manager it is running everything looks fine but I cannot connect it.

This is my nodejs code:

```
const {MongoClient} = require('mongodb')
const url= 'mongodb://localhost:27017';
const databaseName='e-comm'
const client= new MongoClient(url);

async function getData()
{
    let result = await client.connect();
    db = result.db(databaseName);
    collection = db.collection('products');
    let data = await collection.find({}).toArray();
    console.log(data)
}

getData();
```

Comment: This script works fine for me. What if you go to `http://localhost:27017/` in your browser (to make sure Mongo is running) ?

Comment: You can also try to connect from [Mongo Shell](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.4/mongo/) in command line to make sure everything works fine with `mongo "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017"`.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add `const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');` in your code and also pass `{useUnifiedTopology: true,useNewUrlParser: true}` in MongoClient Constructure after url parameter as a best practice

Answer (score 1):

If you use `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` in your `URL`, it will probably solve the problem.

Comment: This worked for me.
I then remembered there is a reroute defined for localhost on my computer...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var mongoUri = mongodb://yourusername:yourpassword@127.0.0.1:27017/?retryWrites=false&ssl=true&authSource=YourDB&sslValidate=false&directConnection=true
var databaseName = "YourDB"

const mongoClient = new MongoClient(mongoUri);
const db = mongoClient.db(databaseName);
```

Things only worked when I started to put `&sslValidate=false&directConnection=true` to the uri.